# Why is my Switch always off when the controller is presented?

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I made a **SwitchRow** with **Eureka** but can't get it to work that my switch saves it current state. It is always shown as off when the **SettingsView** is presented modally. It is a little bit irritating because I save the row value to the **UserDefaults** and you can't tell if it is on or not. Here is my code:

```
class SettingsView : FormViewController{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
            +++ Section("Messages")
            <<< SwitchRow("message_people_withId") { row in
                row.title = "Activate messages"
            }.onChange { row in
                row.title = (row.value ?? false) ? "Deactivate messages" : "Activate messages"
                row.updateCell()
                UserDefaults.standard.set(row.value ?? false, forKey: "MessageSettingsRow")

            }
```

This creates a switch which changes the title if the user turns it off or on. But the ui changes are not reflected. I thought the best way would be to check for the switch row itself and change its value depending on the row value:

```
 if row.value == true {
                    (self.form.rowBy(tag: "message_people_withId") as? SwitchRow)?.cell.switchControl.isOn = true
                } else {
                    (self.form.rowBy(tag: "message_people_withId") as? SwitchRow)?.cell.switchControl.isOn = false
                }
```

but this changes nothing.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the `row.value` Therefore making your code similar to;

```
class SettingsView : FormViewController{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
            +++ Section("Messages")
            <<< SwitchRow("message_people_withId") { row in
                row.title = "Activate messages"
                row.value = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "MessageSettingsRow")
            }.onChange { row in
                row.title = (row.value ?? false) ? "Deactivate messages" : "Activate messages"
                row.updateCell()
                UserDefaults.standard.set(row.value ?? false, forKey: "MessageSettingsRow")

            }
```

This will ensure the correct value on `viewDidLoad()`.

Your second code block, the one that evalutes `row.value` to be true or not will always return false given the standard state of the `SwitchRow` is false.

Comment: This always sets the switch to on. DO I have to remove the object when the switch is turned off in order to make it work?

Comment: You need to change `row.value = true` to the value from your user defaults. I can modify the code if you need help with that

Comment: Isn´t the UserDefaults value saved as a **NSString** somewhere in the info.plist file? I would appreciate it.. I literally have no clue at the moment.

Comment: I have amended the answer. The key is, `UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: ) `

Answer (score 0):

Making it simple your row value is not getting updated

```
 print(row.value)
```

You are getting every time true so your switch always on

```
if row.value == true {
                (self.form.rowBy(tag: "message_people_withId") as? SwitchRow)?.cell.switchControl.isOn = true
            } else {
                (self.form.rowBy(tag: "message_people_withId") as? SwitchRow)?.cell.switchControl.isOn = false
            }
```